# Two models pointing to one database table in Django 2.1

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-2.1

I'm working on a Django project made by a former employee of the company (so I'm refactoring a whole project made by somebody else that didn't follow Django Best Practices), that have two models on different apps using the same tables on database. The City and State tables are used in both apps.

I want to know which is the best way to apply DRY concepts and use only one model for the two apps access these tables.

The two apps are on the project folder and each one has his own `models.py` with the following code for city/state:

```py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User,Group
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

class state(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table = '"db_property"."state"'
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(db_column='created_at')
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(db_column='updated_at')
    name = models.CharField(db_column='name',max_length=50)

class city(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table = '"db_property"."city"'
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(db_column='created_at')
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(db_column='updated_at')
    name = models.CharField(db_column='name',max_length=50)
    state = models.ForeignKey(state,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: I don't understand why you need to define these models twice. Why do you do that?

Comment: I didn't. My question is precisely what I have to do to erase one of the models and the application keep working fine. I'm refactoring the code of somebody else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Am I missing something?

Put `city` and `state` in one or other app, or even in their own `citystate` app, and import them from the place they are defined. In an app called `foo`:

```
from citystate.models import city, state
```

In passing, Django models are `class`es, and as such one would normally start them with a capital letter: `City` and `State`. Honoring conventions like this matter: you may not be confused (yet) but you will confuse the heck out of anybody else reading this code, who will think that these things being imported are functions not classes!

An app is not required to have any views, urls, etc. It can be just a place to put common models and their migrations, and maybe some admin classes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, just to clarify:
Considering that I have this city model in one app, all I have to do is import it in how many views I want to use it in any app inside the project? So I could delete the duplicate model from the other app? Doing this, I have to run makemigrations/migrate to update the database or it won't affect the DB?

About the capital letter convention, I agree. I'm refactoring the whole project made by a former employee. Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, definitely just define in one place and import wherever else needed. I don't know about migrating away from a former bad design, except take great care not to break anything! Removing a model will by default delete its DB table when you migrate ... that's normally right, but not wanted here.

Comment: I'm tending to one app per table, unless there are very closely inter-related models which it makes absolutely no sense to separate. YMMV. I also have a `utils` app where I park everything not tied to the DB and not  specific to one app, like template tags, utility functions, general-purpose templates ....